# Scala: how to construct a regex including a variable?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to test if a `regex` including a variable that I defined before matches a string.

For instance I would like to do :

```
val value = "abc"
regex = "[^a-z]".r + value //something like that
if(regex matches ".abc") print("ok, it works")
```

So my question is : **how can I add construct a regex including a variable in scala?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must quote the value string to protect against special regex syntax.

```
scala> val value = "*"
value: String = *

scala> val oops = """[^a-z]""" + value r
oops: scala.util.matching.Regex = [^a-z]*

scala> ".*" match { case oops() => }

scala> ".....*" match { case oops() => }
```

They added quoting to the Scala API:

```
scala> import util.matching._
import util.matching._

scala> val ok = """[^a-z]""" + Regex.quote(value) r
ok: scala.util.matching.Regex = [^a-z]\Q*\E

scala> ".*" match { case ok() => }

scala> ".....*" match { case ok() => }
scala.MatchError: .....* (of class java.lang.String)
  ... 33 elided
```

You could also generalize the pattern and do additional checks:

```
scala> val r = """\W(\w+)""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = \W(\w+)

scala> ".abc" match { case r(s) if s == "abc" => }
```

Parsing and building the regex itself is relatively expensive, so usually it's desirable to do it once with a general pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and the use of "Pattern.quote". For the generalization of the pattern, I'm aware of this, it was to simplify the question.

Comment: "*" is not a valid regex on its own. Dunno what you want to convey, but the same problem exists with any string you send to .r Adding convolution does not make answers better.

Comment: @uberwach My point was exactly as stated: quote arbitrary strings you intend to treat as literals. Sample bug in the wild: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/1822

Answer (score 8):

```
("[^a-z]" + value).r
```

is all you need

Comment: much simpler and more concise response!

Comment: You really must quote the value. Interpolating an arbitrary value into a regex is not hygienic (in the technical sense).

Comment: no, I must not, let it stand here as an antithesis to voting systems and an incentive to become more "Socratic" (I must quote this)

Comment: OK, if you edit I'll upvote. I came by b/c some benighted soul downvoted without leaving a comment. :) Wait, you're not suggesting Socrates was anti-democratic?

Comment: Just to show how leaky it is. (The real world example is a bug matching a file name where backslash messed up the regex.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150746/use-enumeration-inside-of-regex-pattern-matching#comment71472496_42153160