# Use Enumeration inside of Regex pattern matching

Tags: scala

I have written this code

```
object Foo extends Enumeration {
  val X = Value("X")
  val Y = Value("Y")
}

val regex = """([A-Z]+)(\d+)""".r
val input = "ABC123"

input match {
  case regex(x, num) if x == Foo.X.toString => // do something
  case regex(x, num) if x == Foo.Y.toString => // do something
  case _ => // throw error
}
```

This works but is a little too verbose. I tried to change it to

```
input match {
  case regex(`Foo.X.toString`, num) => // do something
  case regex(`Foo.Y.toString`, num) => // do something
  case _ => // throw error
}
```

But this does not compile. Apartently those ``` work for "vals" but not for enumerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that someone has asked for this feature, except that most people avoid Enumeration now:

```
scala> object E extends Enumeration {
     |   val X, Y = Value
     |   def unapply(s: String): Option[Value] = values.find(_.toString == s)
     | }
defined object E

scala> val r = "([A-Z]+)".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = ([A-Z]+)

scala> "Y" match { case r(E(e)) => e }
res0: E.Value = Y

scala> "Y" match { case r(E(E.Y)) => }
```

Note the hazards of constructing a regex from arbitrary strings:

```
scala> object E extends Enumeration { val X, Y, Z_* = Value }
defined object E

scala> val r = E.values.mkString("|").r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = X|Y|Z_$times

scala> object E extends Enumeration { val X, Y = Value ; val Z = Value("*") }
defined object E

scala> val r = E.values.mkString("|").r
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 4
X|Y|*
    ^
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2123)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
  at scala.util.matching.Regex.<init>(Regex.scala:209)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r(StringLike.scala:287)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r$(StringLike.scala:287)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:29)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r(StringLike.scala:276)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r$(StringLike.scala:276)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:29)
  ... 29 elided

scala> object E extends Enumeration { val X, Y = Value ; val Z = Value(".*") }
defined object E

scala> val r = E.values.mkString("|").r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = X|Y|.*

scala> "junk" match { case r() => }
```