# Is there a way for embedding the value of one regular expression in another one in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I have some regex values that I need to use as variables for a new regex.

I want to write something like:

```
val lowers: Regex = "[a-z]”.r

val uppers: Regex = "[A-Z]”.r

val letters: Regex = “(lowers | uppers)*”.r
```

But I don’t know the right syntax for it.

If it’s possible, how can it be done in Scala?

**Edit**

As suggested in the comments, this [question](http://https:/stackoverflow.com/questions/28927533/%E2%80%A6) is also related to this one when the regex variable is to be added outside the regex, which does not seem to be solving the problem here.

Comment: `val letters: Regex = "[A-Za-z]*".r`. Or, do you mean you have some regex values that you need to use as variables for a new regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean the latter. regex values to use as variables for a new one.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927533/scala-how-to-construct-a-regex-including-a-variable help?

Comment: Do you need `val letters: Regex = s"($lowers|$uppers)*".r`? See [this Scala demo](https://rextester.com/CVBINW74406).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the suggestions. I looked at the link. It was interesting and relevant. The problem is that, when putting it inside the String, it does not recognize the syntax. Same with the `$lowers` notation.

Comment: See https://rextester.com/CVBINW74406

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much for your help. I put the `s` for recognizing the variable, as in the link you posted, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string interpolation to construct a regex from two other strings:

```scala
val lowers: Regex = "[a-z]".r
val uppers: Regex = "[A-Z]".r
val letters: Regex = s"($lowers|$uppers)*".r
```

Please mind the `s` prefix before the initial `"` of the string literal.
Output:

```scala
([a-z]|[A-Z])*
```

Note you should be careful with spaces in the pattern, whitespace is meaningful by default.

If you want to use spaces just for formatting, for ease of reading the regex, you can use the `(?x)` [`COMMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS) ("verbose", "freespacing") modifier:

```scala
val letters: Regex = s"(?x)($lowers | $uppers)*".r
```

Mind you need to escape any literal whitespace char (tab, space, newline) in the pattern if you want to use this feature. Also, you will have to escape a `#` char as it becomes special in this mode.